# Magento 2: User get Redirected to Empty Cart Page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onestepcheckout

When I placed order from checkout page with `money order`. User get redirected to empty cart page instead of success page.

I am using one step checkout in website.

Comment: You should check error log.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a temporary fix, it is not as per magento 2 standard. But as there is some existing issue with session in magento 2 and I have seen many of people facing same issue. I am sharing this temporary fix. Soon, I will update you with Correct answer.

Under vendor controller `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage` open `success.php` file `\vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success.php`

Just comment this line of code:

`// return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');`

OR

you can create an observer for `Success.php` and custamize success controller.

Comment: Did you ever get an update?

Comment: Is this proper solution?

Comment: I try this solution and worked but as you said is a temporary solution. Any update?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any updates on this? I'm running across this now and seeing that this post is about 1-2 years old.. Is it still the appropriate fix, even if it's a `temporary fix`. It's unacceptable to be giving customers a confusing experience like this.. they are spending money, order is executing and they are getting a `cart-empty` page :(

Answer (score 0):

We are too (Magento Commerce Cloud 2.2.5) -- but for any payment type, not just MO.  Magento Support issued us a patch that addresses the PHP issue regarding secure sessions and referral checks...

... but that didn't fix the problem for us -- still getting random redirects to empty cart after the user presses Place Order (potential race condition).

```
MDVA-10441_EE_2.3.3_v3.composer

diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Index/Index.php b/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Index/Index.php
index 0a5b7f190e3..9fe760d3fa7 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Index/Index.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Index/Index.php
@@ -32,11 +32,37 @@ class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
             return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
         }

-        $this->_customerSession->regenerateId();
+        // generate session ID only if connection is unsecure according to issues in session_regenerate_id function.
+        // @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php
+        if (!$this->isSecureRequest()) {
+            $this->_customerSession->regenerateId();
+        }
         $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session::class)->setCartWasUpdated(false);
         $this->getOnepage()->initCheckout();
         $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
         $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Checkout'));
         return $resultPage;
     }
+
+    /**
+     * Checks if current request uses SSL and referer also is secure.
+     *
+     * @return bool
+     */
+    private function isSecureRequest(): bool
+    {
+        $secure = false;
+        $request = $this->getRequest();
+
+        if ($request->isSecure()) {
+            $secure = true;
+        }
+
+        if ($request->getHeader('referer')) {
+            $scheme = parse_url($request->getHeader('referer'), PHP_URL_SCHEME);
+            $secure = $scheme === 'https';
+        }
+
+        return $secure;
+    }
 }
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js b/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js
index f0679c657ab..0bb0a53ce0a 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/proceed-to-checkout.js
@@ -22,6 +22,7 @@ define([

                 return false;
             }
+            $(element).attr('disabled', true);
             location.href = config.checkoutUrl;
         });

diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js b/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js
index 13a2b524e51..93a78e7d34c 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js
@@ -60,13 +60,15 @@ define([
             };
             events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function () {
                 var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
-                    customer = customerData.get('customer');
+                    customer = customerData.get('customer'),
+                    element = $(this.options.button.checkout);

                 if (!customer().firstname && cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed === false) {
                     // set URL for redirect on successful login/registration. It's postprocessed on backend.
                     $.cookie('login_redirect', this.options.url.checkout);

                     if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
+                        element.prop('disabled', true);
                         location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                     } else {
                         authenticationPopup.showModal();
@@ -74,6 +76,7 @@ define([

                     return false;
                 }
+                element.prop('disabled', true);
                 location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
             }, this);

diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerNotification.php b/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerNotification.php
index 3f73c8cdaee..2181e5b4578 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerNotification.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Plugin/CustomerNotification.php
@@ -85,11 +85,36 @@ class CustomerNotification
                 $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                 $this->session->setCustomerData($customer);
                 $this->session->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId());
-                $this->session->regenerateId();
+                if (!$this->isSecureRequest($request)) {
+                    $this->session->regenerateId();
+                }
                 $this->notificationStorage->remove(NotificationStorage::UPDATE_CUSTOMER_SESSION, $customerId);
             } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                 $this->logger->error($e);
             }
         }
     }
+
+    /**
+     * Checks if current request uses SSL and referer also is secure.
+     *
+     * @param RequestInterface $request
+     *
+     * @return bool
+     */
+    private function isSecureRequest(RequestInterface $request)
+    {
+        $secure = false;
+
+        if ($request->isSecure()) {
+            $secure = true;
+        }
+
+        if ($request->getHeader('referer')) {
+            $scheme = parse_url($request->getHeader('referer'), PHP_URL_SCHEME);
+            $secure = $scheme === 'https';
+        }
+
+        return $secure;
+    }
 }
```

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am having issue with third party online payments (eWay) only. PayPal, Bank Transfer takes to the success page.